# Location awareness

Tags: javascript

I have this javascript code which takes a list of locations and reorders the list items according to the users location. how can i change the code so that it only displays the locations within a vicinity of 1KM rather than just reordering the whole list.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
});
</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
function findMe() {
if (navigator.geolocation != undefined) {
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onFound, onError);
}
}
function onFound(pos) {
var userLat = pos.coords.latitude;
var userLong = pos.coords.longitude;
$('ol li').each(function (index) {
var locationLat = $(this).find('.lat').html();
var locationLong = $(this).find('.long').html();
var distance = getDistance(userLat, locationLat, userLong, locationLong);
$(this).data("distance", distance);
})

reOrder();
}

function onError(pos) {
alert("Something Went wrong");
}

function reOrder() {
$('ol li').sort(sortAlpha).appendTo('ol');
}

function sortAlpha(a, b) {
return $(a).data('distance') > $(b).data('distance') ? 1 : -1;
};

function getDistance(lat1, lat2, lon1, lon2) {
var R = 6371; // km
var d = Math.acos(Math.sin(lat1) * Math.sin(lat2) +
Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2) *
Math.cos(lon2 - lon1)) * R;
return d;

}; 
</script>

<style>
ol .long, ol .lat
{
display: none;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like this:

```
function filterList(){
   $('ol li').each(function(){
      if($(this).data('distance') > 1){
        $(this).remove();
      }
   });
}
```

Instead of above solution you can do following?

```
function onFound(pos) {
   var userLat = pos.coords.latitude;
   var userLong = pos.coords.longitude;
   $('ol li').each(function (index) {
      var locationLat = $(this).find('.lat').html();
      var locationLong = $(this).find('.long').html();
      var distance = getDistance(userLat, locationLat, userLong, locationLong);
      if(Math.ceil(distance)>1){
         $(this).remove();
      }
      else{
         $(this).data("distance", distance);
      }
  });
 reOrder();
}
```

You can remove filterList function. I hope it works now for you.

Comment: You can have this function anywhere but you have to call this function instead of reOrder

Comment: i have tried having that function instead of reOrder, but it is not working. is there anything you may know is wrong.

Comment: I made some amends above. use data('distance') for comparing as you are using data('distance') in alphaSort as well.

Comment: i cant seem to get it working, unfortunately. would you be able to insert it into the code please.

Comment: this is the last part i need, and i just cant seem to get it done. thank you, it  is much appreciated